# Middle div should get remaining width. Works in Firefox but not IE. Why?

Tags: internet-explorer, html, width

I have a div containing 3 divs. The div to the left and right each have their width set to 200px and the middle div should get all the remaining width. This works fine in Firefox but not in IE8 and IE9.

Can someone please tell me why this doesn't work in IE?

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="outercontainer" style="width:100%;overflow:hidden;">
    <div class"fixedtablediv" style="width:200px;float:right;">
        <table id="signtable" class="patable">
        <thead>
            <tr style="height: 101px;" class="headstyle" id="signtableheadtr"> 
            <td style="text-align: left;"><b>Summa</b></td>
            <td style="text-align: left;"><b>Godk.&nbsp;<input name="trigger" tabindex="-1" value="appr" onclick="checkAll(0, this, this.value)" type="checkbox"></b></td>
            <td style="text-align: left;"><b>Spärr&nbsp;<input name="trigger1" tabindex="-1" value="block" onclick="checkAll(0, this, this.value)" type="checkbox"></b></td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="rowlight">
            <td style="text-align: right;">40.00</td>
            <td style="text-align: left;"><input name="appr" value="0" type="checkbox"></td>
            <td style="text-align: left;"><input name="block" value="0" type="checkbox"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="rowdark">
            <td style="text-align: right;">32.00</td>
            <td style="text-align: left;"><input name="appr" value="1" type="checkbox"></td>
            <td style="text-align: left;"><input name="block" value="1" type="checkbox"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>        
    </div>  
    <div class"fixedtablediv" style="width:200px;float:left;">
        <table id="nametable">
        <thead id="nametablehead" style="vertical-align:bottom;">
            <tr class="headstyle" id='nametableheadtr'>
                <td style="text-align: left;"><a class="" href="/hrm/web?palette=0&amp;value=&amp;funcid=F_PAC_10"><b>Firstname</b></a></td>
                <td style="text-align: left;"><a class="" href="/hrm/web?palette=0&amp;value=&amp;funcid=F_PAC_11"><b>Lastname</b></a></td>
                <td style="text-align: left;"><a class="" href="/hrm/web?palette=0&amp;value=&amp;funcid=F_PAC_12"><b>Id</b></a></td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>     
            <tr class="rowlight" onmouseover="this.style.background = '#EED';" onmouseout="this.style.background = '';"> 
                <td style="text-align: left;">Gunnar</td><td style="text-align: left;">Svensson</td>
                <td style="text-align: left;">123</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="rowdark" onmouseover="this.style.background = '#EED';" onmouseout="this.style.background = '';"> 
                <td style="text-align: left;">Sven</td>
                <td style="text-align: left;">Svensson</td>
                <td style="text-align: left;">789</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="scrolldiv" style="overflow:auto;margin-left:200px;margin-right:200px;">
        <table id="projecttable">
            <thead id="projtablehead">
            <tr class="headstyle">
                <td colspan="47" style="text-align: left;"><b>Projects</b></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="headstyle">
                <td style="text-align: left;"><b>M123-ABC DBF Proc</b></td>
                <td style="text-align: left;"><b>Meetings and Reviews</b></td>
                <td style="text-align: left;"><b>R9/Offertarbete Max</b></td>
                <td style="text-align: left;"><b>R9/Offertarbete flights</b></td>
                <td style="text-align: left;"><b>R1/ABC12 Planning &amp; Project control</b></td>
                <td style="text-align: left;"><b>RU123/ABC12 Contract Admi</b></td>
                <td style="text-align: left;"><b>RU13/ABC12 Product Assurance</b></td>
                <td style="text-align: left;"><b>RU121/ABC12 LS Planning</b></td>
                <td style="text-align: left;"><b>RU12242/ABC12 LS execution</b></td>
                <td style="text-align: left;"><b>RU11/ABC12 LS Plan and Final REP.</b></td>
                <td style="text-align: left;"><b>RU52/ABC12 LS Pre and post campaign</b></td>
                <td style="text-align: left;"><b>RU61/ABC12 LS Campaign Mngmt</b></td>
                <td style="text-align: left;"><b>RU62/ABC12 LS Campaign execution</b></td>
                <td style="text-align: left;"><b>RU29/ABC12 P/L System engineering</b></td>
                <td style="text-align: left;"><b>R1/Planning&amp;Project control</b></td>
                <td style="text-align: left;"><b>R1/Contract Admi</b></td>
                <td style="text-align: left;"><b>R1/Prod Assurance</b></td>
                <td style="text-align: left;"><b>R1/System engineering</b></td>
                <td style="text-align: left;"><b>R1/B3 mgmt</b></td>
                <td style="text-align: left;"><b>R1/B3 Meetings and Reviews</b></td>
                <td style="text-align: left;"><b>R1/B3 Sys Eng</b></td>
                <td style="text-align: left;"><b>R1/IMP Mgmt</b></td>
                <td style="text-align: left;"><b>R1/IMP Meetings and Reviews</b></td>
                <td style="text-align: left;"><b>R1/IMPACHT Sys Eng</b></td>
                <td style="text-align: left;"><b>R1/CD  mgmt</b></td>
                <td style="text-align: left;"><b>R1/CD  Sys Eng</b></td>
                <td style="text-align: left;"><b>RA8/Management &amp; PA</b></td>
                <td style="text-align: left;"><b>RA8/C Re-entry cone</b></td>
                <td style="text-align: left;"><b>RA9/Management and PA</b></td>
                <td style="text-align: left;"><b>RA95/Ext Meetings and Design Review</b></td>
                <td style="text-align: left;"><b>RA9/System Engineering</b></td>
                <td style="text-align: left;"><b>RA9/New TMSystem dev. t.</b></td>
                <td style="text-align: left;"><b>RA9/Guidance and control system</b></td>
                <td style="text-align: left;"><b>RA95/ABC proc manuf. and design</b></td>
                <td style="text-align: left;"><b>RA95/assembly and test</b></td>
                <td style="text-align: left;"><b>RA9/ Proc manuf. and design</b></td>
                <td style="text-align: left;"><b>RA9/assembly and test</b></td>
                <td style="text-align: left;"><b>RA9/INA integration and test</b></td>
                <td style="text-align: left;"><b>RA9/system integration and test</b></td>
                <td style="text-align: left;"><b>RA9/Fin assembly</b></td>
                <td style="text-align: left;"><b>RA9/motor</b></td>
                <td style="text-align: left;"><b>RA9/transport</b></td>
                <td style="text-align: left;"><b>RA9/review and end to end test</b></td>
                <td style="text-align: left;"><b>RA9/Prep</b></td>
                <td style="text-align: left;"><b>RA9/campaign</b></td>
                <td style="text-align: left;"><b>RA9/Flight Work</b></td>
                <td style="text-align: left;"><b>RA9/8 Study</b></td>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr class="rowlight" onmouseover="this.style.background = '#EED';" onmouseout="this.style.background = '';"> <td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"><span title="2013-03-04&nbsp;8.00&nbsp;Projekttid&nbsp;2013-03-05&nbsp;4.00&nbsp;Projekttid&nbsp;2013-03-06&nbsp;3.00&nbsp;Projekttid&nbsp;">15.00</span></td><td style="text-align: right;"><span title="2013-03-06&nbsp;5.00&nbsp;Projekttid&nbsp;">5.00</span></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"><span title="2013-03-07&nbsp;8.00&nbsp;Projekttid&nbsp;">8.00</span></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td></tr>
                <tr class="rowdark" onmouseover="this.style.background = '#EED';" onmouseout="this.style.background = '';"> <td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"><span title="2013-03-04&nbsp;8.00&nbsp;Projekttid&nbsp;2013-03-05&nbsp;8.00&nbsp;Projekttid&nbsp;">16.00</span></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"><span title="2013-03-06&nbsp;8.00&nbsp;Projekttid&nbsp;">8.00</span></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td><td style="text-align: right;"></td></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looks like you are in [quirksmode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode). You should include a DOCTYPE declaration i.e.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
or
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I have tried to solve this for a long time. You made my day! I hope you have a greate day too! :-)

Comment: The solution works, but it turns out that I can´t add the <DOCTYPE html> tag because it change the rest of the pages in a negative way. Can you solve this some other way?

Comment: Hi @user1297771, this is the correct answer to the original question - why the layout looks broken in IE 8 & 9. If other code you've created relies on IE quirksmode, you should probably fix it! You can create new questions for specific issues as they arise. Glad to be of help.